# Handling messages when composing with list of widgets in Elm

Tags: elm

In a few [guides](https://www.elm-tutorial.org/en-v01/02-elm-arch/07-composing-2.html), message handling in parent components is made like this;

```
type Msg
    = NavMsg Nav.Msg
    | SidebarMsg Sidebar.Msg
    | WidgetMsg Widget.Msg
```

And parent components handle them in updates with:

```
update : Msg -> AppModel -> (AppModel, Cmd Msg)
update message model =
    case message of
        WidgetMsg subMsg ->
            let
                (updatedWidgetModel, widgetCmd) =
                    Widget.update subMsg model.widgetModel
            in
                ({ model | widgetModel = updatedWidgetModel }, Cmd.map WidgetMsg widgetCmd)
        _ ->
```

However, I couldn't find a simple way to do the same if the child components are inside a list. How can I tell the correct sub component to react to a message directed to him?

I thought of adding the component object to the message:

```
type Msg
    = MessageToParent
    | MessageToChild Child Child.Msg
```

But this seems very inefficient if the Child component is big, and still gives me trouble when trying to delegate the inner `Child.Msg` to the right `Child`.

What's the best way to handle message passing to a list of components?

Comment: [The Guide](https://guide.elm-lang.org/reuse/) covers "component" reuse in Elm, and it says _"We do not think in terms of reusable components. Instead, we focus on reusable functions."_

Comment: So? That's a matter of nomenclature, the question still stands. How to compose with a list of functions.

Comment: Maybe something like making child views "configurable" through an aditional parameter could help. This package is a good example of this pattern https://github.com/evancz/elm-sortable-table/blob/master/src/Table.elm . Combine this with some curring and you only need to write one config parameter for each type of child view.

Comment: Can you post the code of interest?  The code you posted does not include a "list of components" so it's not entirely clear what you need.  I would suggest the previous comment was correct though.  Read the next page in that section of the guide.  https://guide.elm-lang.org/reuse/checkboxes.html It explicitly states elm has "No parent-child communication."  This is both a goal and a feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using an array (or Dict) and code like this

```
type Msg
    = WidgetMsg Int Widget.Msg

update : Msg -> AppModel -> (AppModel, Cmd Msg)
update message model =
    case message of
        WidgetMsg idx subMsg ->
            model.widgetModels
                |> Array.get idx
                |> Maybe.map (Widget.update subMsg)
                |> Maybe.map (\(m,c) -> 
                     ({ model | widgetModels = Array.set idx m model.widgetModels }
                     , Cmd.map Widgetmsg idx c)
                     )
                |> Maybe.withDefault (model, Cmd.none)
        _ ->
```